# Rails is rendering a javascript .js.erb file in the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a situation in Rails 5.2 where a controller is rendering a `.js.erb` file to the view **literally**, i.e. showing the javascript code in the view itself.

How can I get Rails to run the `js.erb` file instead of showing it as if it were a DOM file? It is taking the user away from a page I want the user to stay on.

```
# controller
def submit_custom_data
  ...perform some functions...
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end

# submit_custom_data.js.erb
console.log('submit_custom_data...');
... Other javascript ...
```

#### Additional Info

By preserving the browser console logs on Chrome, I see this:

Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type text/javascript: "http://localhost:3000/submit_custom_data/1068.js?c=1&d=10&db=1&s=8&tm=&w=3".
Navigated to http://localhost:3000/submit_custom_data/1068.js?c=1&d=10&db=1&s=8&tm=&w=3

This issue did NOT occur on Rails 4.2.7. After updating to Rails 5.2.7 (and updating the bundle), I'm now seeing these issues.

Comment: Can you update the question with the related code?

Comment: @Pavan I added the code - nothing that interesting as far as I can tell.

Comment: Do you see any errors in the browser console? Can you also a screenshot of the view to the question?

Comment: @Pavan I wanted to check that but there's nothing to see because the entire view just shows the contents of `submit_custom_data.js.erb`.

Comment: What is the dataType in your Ajax call? it should be `dataType : 'script'`

Comment: It is 'script'. The ajax call actually goes to requests/create, which redirects to submit_custom_data. The redirect happens in JS format (the server confirms that submit_custom_data being processed 'as JS').